# Is this a legal use of passing struct/int/float... type to memcpy to copy on char data area?

Tags: c, struct, buffer, memcpy

Can I use `memcpy` to copy data of one data type to another data type...

let's say I have `char buffer[1024]`, now I want to copy my `struct abc x;` of size 306 (for example) into `buffer`..

So Is this legal/possible use without any unexpected behavior?

`memcpy(buffer, &x, sizeof(x));`

Then there would be any unexpected behavior if I copy back that data to `struct abc y;`?

`memcpy(&y, &buffer, sizeof(struct abc));`

and also if I have `struct abc *z`,

`z = (struct abc *) buffer;`

I try to extract `struc abc` from buffer.

I tried my best to explain myself please ignore or suggest if you observe any mistake...

Comment: No. You should do `memcpy(buffer, &x, sizeof(x));`.

Comment: @MikeCAT yeah, sorry that was my typo.. now edited ..

Comment: It is "legal" in the sense that you can do it; just what the 2 datatypes are will have some influence on the expectedness of the resulting behavior.

Comment: @ScottHunter That's what I am curious about.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question; care to narrow it down a bit?  For example, if you copied your struct to a buffer, and then from that buffer to another instance of that struct, you'd be fine.

Comment: @ScottHunter You can tell me  a scenario where buffer data is again copied to ```y``` .

Comment: I have no idea what that sentence means; for starters, what is `y`?

Comment: If you have different structures to copy to/from a buffer, your program should also know what structure was copied to the buffer. There is no help from the compiler to prevent you from copying a `struct abc` to the buffer and later copy data from the buffer to a `struct def` which might produce unexpected results. And when you copy the data from the buffer to system that uses a different OS/processor/compiler, the same structure in source code might not be compatible to the data in the buffer.

Comment: please find the edit , I tried another example.

Comment: " Is this legal/possible use without any unexpected behavior?" --> in the by gone era of non 2's compliment, forming a `char` with a trap value was a risk.  Even today, best to for the copy buffer to be `unsigned char` rather than `char` to mitigate subsequent buffer uses.

Comment: Jarvis__-_-__: `void buffer[size];` is not standard C.  Best to post true compliable code.

Comment: wait guys let me edit again.

Comment: now please find the edit..

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. As some people already said, yes it is indeed legal. About the undefined behaviour. Well, it is pretty safe to say that sizeof(x) == sizeof(y) == sizeof(struct abc). So you should be fine. Anyway that's kind of counterintuitive.

Comment: Re the `z = (struct abc *) buffer;` example: The C standard **does not** guarantee that it will work. Within a specific system it will (nearly always) work but if you are strict about complying to the standard the don't do such stuff.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This:

```
char buffer[1024];
struct abc x;
// Init x
memcpy(buffer, &x, sizeof(x));
struct abc y;
memcpy(&y, buffer, sizeof(y));
```

will ensure that if you have a function `T foo(struct abc arg)` where `T` could be any type, then `T a = foo(x);` and `T a = foo(y);` will behave the same. Except if `sizeof(struct abc)` is larger than the buffer.

However, if you do this:

```
puts(buffer);
```

It's not guaranteed to give the same printout. This means that if you write the buffer to a file or send it via network to another machine, then a program running on another machine may be unable to read it properly.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. and what if I want to extract from ```buffer```?

Comment: @Jarvis__-_-__ Then you simply need to write functions for that that does not assume anything about size of data types, padding or endianess.

Comment: so the data will remain safe or any undefined behavior will be observed?

Comment: @Jarvis__-_-__ Doing this wrong does not necessarily produce UB

Comment: Okey got it!  , Thanks for your response and clearing my doubt```:)```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already addressed the `memcpy` part. And yes, it's fine to use `memcpy` to **copy an object of type T** into a char buffer and later use `memcpy` to copy the data from the char buffer back **to an object of type T**. No problem.

In this answer I'll address the last part of the question, i.e. is it okay to do:

```
memcpy(buffer, &x, sizeof(x));
z = (struct abc *) buffer;
```

The answer is: **No, it's not safe according to the C standard**

One issue is that the buffer isn't guaranteed to preserve the alignment requirements of the struct members.

On modern systems (at least all modern systems, I know) it will work just fine but if you want to be strict about complying to the C standard, you shouldn't do such things.

Answer (score -2):

`memcpy` way is correct and it will not invoke Undefined Behaviour. Most modern compilers know how the `memcpy` function works and in many circumstances they will not call it.

Example:

```
struct abc
{
    int a,b,c;
    double d,e,f;
}x;

void foo(void *ptr)
{
    memcpy(&x, ptr, sizeof(x));
}

foo:
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR x[rip], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR x[rip+16], xmm1
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+32]
        mov     QWORD PTR x[rip+32], rax
        ret
```

Pointer punning is not safe and you should not use it (if you want to know why - read about strict aliasing rule [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)).

Comment: Thanks for your response , I will definitely look for it..